# Join path that overlaps

Tags: java, string, path

In java, I have a string that looks like :

```
"c:\abc\def\ghi"
```

and another that is

```
"def\ghi\jkl.txt"
```

How can I do the intersection of both to have

```
"c:\abc\def\ghi\jkl.txt"
```

edit :

The rules are :

replace the maximum of the end of the first string with the maximum of the beginning of the second string.

For example with

- b\a\n\a\n\a and a\n\a\n\a\s the result should be b\a\n\a\n\a\s
- with "c:\abc\def\ghi" joined to "def\gji\jkl.txt", we have "c:\abc\def\ghi\def\gji\jkl.txt"

Comment: you 1st have to define the proper rules for the joining. What do "c:\abc\def\ghi" joined to "def\gji\jkl.txt" give, for example?

Comment: In particular, what should you get from joining `b\a\n\a\n\a` to `a\n\a\n\a\s` - should it be `b\a\n\a\n\a\s` or `b\a\n\a\n\a\n\a\n\a\s` ?

Comment: in fact, that is the same path, but I don't have the beginning, so I have to join the path that start with the same of the beginning of the other

Comment: Right.  Your comment is no clearer than your original question.  So you need to think about exactly what the rules are, then update your question to express them more clearly.

Comment: Also take into account, that there could be a subfolder with the same name as the parent folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply look at the first string and check if it ends with the largest possible beginning of the second string. To be a little bit faster I check on every existing backslash:

```
public static String join(String begin, String end) {
    for (int i = end.lastIndexOf("\\"); i >= 0; i = end.lastIndexOf("\\", i - 1)) {
        if (begin.endsWith(end.substring(0, i)) && begin.charAt(begin.length() - (i+1)) == '\\') {
            return begin + end.substring(i);
        }
    }
    return "strings dont contain same folder sequence";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, so there's no pre-made method in java

Comment: At least I'm not aware of it.